# Camunda - change parent of multi instance subprocess

Tags: java, spring, bpmn, camunda

I have a multi instance subprocess in my workflow. There are 2 user activities in this multi instance subprocess.

In my first run, there are 3 instances created for the subprocess and 3 of them are waiting in first user activity. In my second run, there are 2 instances created for the subprocess and 2 of them are waiting in second user activity.

Now I want to move one of the subprocess instances from first run to second run and it should resume from first user activity. How do I do this? Can I update the parent process id of this subprocess instance to second run's parent ID? Will this work?

Comment: Same answer as in the Camunda Forum. It is NOT possible.

Comment: Do you know hey this feature is not added in Camunda? Do you think whether there is any work around for this? Our project design is stuck at here.

Comment: You could cancel the process instance and with the help of the modification API start at the activity you want.